# Setting the index for a pandas dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, database, function, dictionary

The code below creates a bunch of data tables form the dictionary below. I am trying to add `Values` as the index parameter for all the data tables but they all the table values turn into `nan`. How will I be able to change it so that the Indexes `0 to 2` are replaced with `First, Second, Third`.

Dictionary:

```
Outcomes = {
    'Values':{
        'First': {
            'option 1': np.array([12,345,5412]),
            'option 2': np.array([2315,32,1]),
            'option 3': {'row 1': np.array([232,3,1]),
                         'row 2': np.array([3,4,5]),
                         'row 3': np.array([15,6,12])}
        }
        
    }
}
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

Values = ['First', 'Second', 'Third']

def get_nested_df(dic, concat_key="", df_dic=dict()):
   rows = {k:v for k,v in dic.items() if not isinstance(v, dict)}
   if rows:
      df_dic.update({concat_key: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(rows)})
   for k,v in dic.items():
      if isinstance(v, dict):
         get_nested_df(v, f"{concat_key} {k}", df_dic)
   return df_dic

df_dic = get_nested_df(Outcomes)

for k,v in df_dic.items():
    #print(f"{k}\n{v}\n")
    display(pd.DataFrame(v, index=Values).style.set_caption(k).set_table_styles([{
        'selector': 'caption',
        'props': [
            ('color', 'red'),
            ('font-size', '16px'),
            ('text-align', 'center')
        ]
    }]))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: `v` is already a DataFrame so you can set its index with `v.index = Values`. Do you want to render your tables as HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the next code instead:

```
for k,v in df_dic.items():
    #print(f"{k}\n{v}\n")
    v.index = pd.Index(Values)
    v.style.set_caption(k).set_table_styles([{
        'selector': 'caption',
        'props': [
            ('color', 'red'),
            ('font-size', '16px'),
            ('text-align', 'center')
        ]
    }])
    display(v)
```